# How to convert subprocess.call to requests in this example

Tags: python

I find myself using too much `subprocess.call(...)`. The code with this construct looks rather messy, so I want to migrate to [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/) library, however, I feel a lack of examples and can't figure out from documentation how should I use this library to convert this kind of subprocess.call:

```
subprocess.call(['curl','-X','-POST', '-H', 'Content-type:application/json',
'--data-binary','{"delete-dynamic-field":{"name":"attr_*"}}', url])
```

I think every time when I see `subprocess.call(['curl'...`, it's a good idea for me to use another more appropriate library like `requests`.

**EDIT**

I tried this approach:

```
requests.post(url,data={"delete-dynamic-field":{"name":"attr_*"}},
              headers={"Content-type":"application/json"})
```

But I get an error. I wish there were more tiny examples.

Comment: i agree with you. or was there a question?

Comment: If you read the title, you can see there a clear question. And if you read back the body of the message, then you will see there such words as "how should I use this library to convert this kind of subprocess.call". Have a nice day, buddy )

Comment: ok, sorry. now with the example it's much clearer... could you add the `url`? (not necessarily the top-level, but if there are parameters in there it may help).

Comment: Hm. What I have in EDIT block now seems to work.